# Partial View Rendering with ASP.NET MVC 2.0

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a partial View which contains a TextArea.
When i Render this parital view in my main view page the Text Area is coming disabled (but it not graying out) and not allowing any entry to be typed there.

```
//---Here are the code segement from my partial view---

<div id="AddComment" style="display:none">
      <fieldset>
          <legend>Add Comment</legend> 
          <p><label> Comment for:</label>- <select id="Station"></select></p>
          **<%=Html.TextArea("UserComment", new { rows = 5, cols = 65})%>**** (this text area is  the problem)
          <p><input type="button" id="addComment" onclick="SaveComment()" value="Save" /></p>
      </fieldset> 
 </div>
//-----end of code segment -----------------------
```

Please help

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have any javascript that is disabling the textarea?

Comment: With "display:none;" set, it shouldn't be showing up at all. How can you tell that the textarea is disabled?

Comment: there is not code in my which is diabling the TextArea.infact it is the TextBox control also which is getting disabled.if i remder this view in a new HTML page this work...The 'Display:none' is for hiding that seciton'

Comment: Something is missing here, textareas don't just render disabled

Comment: Intially i was rendering the partial view called "Comments" on a new HTML page. but recentry i c hanged my designed and added a DIV in the parent page and rendering this comments inside this DIV.after doing this changes only the problem of disabled TextArea is coming (i don;t know it disabled or not 'coz it not allowing typing but allwing pasting)...lastly i am making this DIV as accordion with jquery UI plugin...is there somethign wrong there???

Comment: you definately have javascript interfering with your textarea, disable the accordion script and see if it works like you want

Comment: even if I don;t make the DIV containing the Partial view accordion the textarea not allowing me to type.

Comment: This is strange..looking at the other section of the program it looks like no input control is accepting any keypress in my program..wheather its a TextArea or input text box..dont; know what wrong but its looks like something is wrong at the jquery UI plugin side. any guess???

Comment: I got the probem resolved. its was not the fault of the partial view Rendering.it was basically the script written on the main page to block the backspace keypress.//--------------------below line of code prevents the browser to raise a backspace key press outside the editor---//
        //document.attachEvent('onkeydown', function(evt) { evt.returnValue = false; });
        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------//...once i removed this line thing started working. thanks you all for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

I got the probem resolved. its was not the fault of the partial view Rendering.it was basically the script written on the main page to block the backspace keypress.

//--------------------below line of code prevents the browser to raise a backspace key press outside the editor---// //document.attachEvent('onkeydown', function(evt) { evt.returnValue = false; }); //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------//...

once i removed this line thing started working. thanks you all for helping me